# Displaying images from webpages in Tkinter [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a little program that opens a headline, picture, and summary from a magazine (the Australian Aviation magazine), that opens up a page with the logo/name, and a picture, with some buttons down the bottom to select the different catergories. Right now I'm having three problems.

1. I've decided to go with just text for the header of the main page, but when I display it in a Tkinter window, it has a set of {} around it. How do I get rid of them? My code for that is below.

   ```
   from urllib import urlopen

   from re import findall

   from Tkinter import *

   from StringIO import StringIO

   from PIL import Image, ImageTk

   url1 = 'http://australianaviation.com.au'

   AAhp = urlopen(url1)

   AAhp_code = AAhp.read()

   AAhp.close()

   AA_title = findall('<title>(.+)</title>', AAhp_code)

   aviation_australia = Tk()

   logo = Label(aviation_australia, text = AA_title, font=('Times', 24))

   logo.pack()

   aviation_australia.mainloop()
   ```
2. I'm also trying to display a webpage image so the intro screen doesn't look as boring, but I don't know how to do that... (keep in mind I've only been using Python for about 10 weeks, and most of that time was with Turtle....)
3. Finally, I really don't know how to make a new page within one Tkinter window, which I am needing. Do I use frames (if so, how do I make four-six be there and become visible/invisible at a button press), or is there some other method?

So yeah, any help would be amazing, thank you in advance! :D

Comment: You are setting the label's `text` to a list! Try `text=AA_title[0]`

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is an easier solution for parsing HTML than regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `AA_title` is a list (the result of a call to `findall`). Under the covers Tkinter uses a Tcl interpreter, and tcl represents lists as elements surrounded by braces.

Assuming you want the value to be only the first item in the list, you need to do something like this:

```
logo = Label(..., text = AA_title[0], ...)
```